# Downloading Artifacts Locally from VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have successfully created a Build definition in VSTS for some SharePoint client side projects that I'm working on. I tried creating a Release definition but I can't seem to find any way for me to copy/download the artifacts created from my build definition locally. I may be missing something since I'm still quite new with VSTS but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean config release definition to download the build artifacts? Or do you want to download artifacts separately?

Comment: Due to some network complexity that we have I was thinkng of having a release definition so that for example after a succssful build all my artifacts will be downloaded to a folder that I can specify.

Answer (score 1):

To downbload build artifacts from release when build successful, you can specify the release definition as below:

1. Add the build artifacts with latest version in release definition.

   [image]
2. Enable Continuous deployment trigger for the artifacts.

   [image]
3. Select the private agent which you want to download on the local machine.

   [image]

Now when a build succeed, a new release will be triggered to download the latest build artifacts.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need to setup my own build agent? Also, there is no task involved here just adding artifacts?

Comment: Yes, you need to setup your private agent, so that the build artifacts will be downloaded on the agent machine. And when you enable  continuous deployment, a new release will be triggered and the artifacts will be downloaded automatically (without adding additional task).

Comment: Once the file is in the agent, how do I download it to my own computer? I think that's what the original poster was asking.